# Search on my multidimensional array list

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [8008] => Array
        (
            [main_mob_vnum] => 8008
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [drop_mob_vnum] => 50300
                    [drop_mob_count] => 2
                    [drop_mob_percent] => 110.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [drop_mob_vnum] => 39030
                    [drop_mob_count] => 2
                    [drop_mob_percent] => 85.00
                )
        )

    [8009] => Array
        (
            [main_mob_vnum] => 8009
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [drop_mob_vnum] => 50300
                    [drop_mob_count] => 4
                    [drop_mob_percent] => 110.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [drop_mob_vnum] => 50125
                    [drop_mob_count] => 1
                    [drop_mob_percent] => 75.00
                )
        )

    [8010] => Array
        (
            [main_mob_vnum] => 8009
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [drop_mob_vnum] => 50125
                    [drop_mob_count] => 4
                    [drop_mob_percent] => 110.00
                )
        )
)
```

I want to make a function like 
`function searchArray($array,$vnum)`
`if $vnum is == with drop_mob_vnum` take the previously array and put all this array keys on new array

For example, `searchArray($array,50300)` should return an array like: `array(8008,8009)` because 8010 doesn't have a `drop_mob_vnum == 50300`

I know StackOverflow requires that I post my problem with code, but I don't know where to start. If someone could help me, I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: try some foreach loop and vardump the results each time. It'll help you find out a solution :D

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick:

```
function find_vnum($array,$value)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array AS $k1 => $v1)
    {
        foreach ($v1 AS $k2 => $v2)
        {
            if ($k2 === 'main_mob_vnum') {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($v2 AS $k3 => $v3)
            {
                if ($k3 !== 'drop_mob_vnum') {
                    continue;
                }

                if (($v3 === $value) && !in_array($k1, $result)) {
                    $result[] = $k1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Given your sample data:

```
print_r(find_vnum($data,50300));

// Array
// (
//    [0] => 8008
//    [1] => 8009
// )
```

You can see a working demo [here](https://eval.in/969880).

Comment: Thanks for your time and for your help! can you check my post down? cause i see that you are using here 3 loops. im using 2 loops to do this i dont know if i have done something wrong but i take the same result :P